# Expressing a sentence in predicate logic

Tags: logic

I need some clarity on predicate logic:

```
Given

D(x)    x is a dog
F(x, y) x is a friend of y
O(x, y) x owns y
h       Harry
s       Susan

express the following sentence in predicate logic

All of Harry's friends are dog owners
```

My understanding is that a predicate cannot be an argument to another predicate.

This is what I think is the solution

```
∃x[F(x, h) ∧ ∀x∃y(D(y) ∧ O(x, y))]
```

Is that valid? To me it reads: Some people are friends of Harry, then that same person definitely own a dog?

Or is the answer the simpler

```
∀x∀y[F(x, h) ∧ D(y) ∧ O(x, y)]
```

But it feels like that says everyone is a friend of Harry

After some input from @Keelan:

```
∀x[F(x, h) → ∃y(O(x, y) ∧ D(y))]
```

Which I read as: For everyone where it is the case that they are friends with Harry, they own y and y is a dog.

Comment: "∀y(O(x, y) ∧ D(y))" means that everything is a dog and is owned by harry's frine. That is nonsense,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first proposal (∃x[F(x, h) ∧ ∀x∃y(D(y) ∧ O(x, y))]), you're assuming Harry has at least one friend, which may not be the case. If he has no friends, the statement is true (see [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)). Also, you're using x both as bounded by ∃ and as bounded by ∀, while the latter is inside the first. This is never allowed.

In your second proposal (∀x∀y[F(x, h) ∧ D(y) ∧ O(x, y)]), you're saying that everyone is a friend of Harry, that everyone is a dog and that everyone owns everyone!

Here are some hints to get you started (since this looks like homework I won't give you a complete solution):

- "All of Harry's friends are dog owners" can be rewritten as "For all people it holds that *if* they are Harry's friend, *then* they are a dog owner"
- "X is a dog owner" can be rewritten as "There is an Y such that Y is a dog and X owns Y"

---

Your third suggestion (∀x[F(x, h) → ∀y(O(x, y) ∧ D(y))]) is almost correct. However, this reads as "For all x holds that if they are friends with Harry, then for all y it holds that x owns y and y is a dog" -- in other words, Harry is a dog as well (and x)!

Comment: I did not consider rewriting the statements, that helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

You should split your sentence into simpler parts and try to express this simple sentence. Then you should compose the more complex sentences.

Try to express "somebody is a friend of harry", e.g t is a friend of Harry

> F(t,h)

"somebody is a dog owner", e.g. x is a dog onwer.

> ∃y(D(y) ∧ O(x,y))

try to Express " all of Harry friends have the property  P" That means for  friend z of Harry P(z) is valid.

> ∀z(F(z,h) → P(z))

Now compose it to the final statement; all of harry's friends are dog owners

> ∀z(F(z,h) → (∃y(D(y) ∧ O(x,y))))

Comment: On my iPad the tinted boxes that contain the quotes are blank.

Comment: @MarkAndrews now the text  is visible

Comment: I can see the text now. Useful answer, by the way. Thanks.